# CustomScrollview with TabBarView that overflows

Tags: flutter, dart, frontend, flutter-layout

So I'm having some difficulty using the following Setup:

```
CustomScrollView(
     slivers: [
          SliverAppBar(...),
          SliverToBoxAdapter(SomeRandomWidget),
          SliverPersistentHeader(TabBar),
          SliverFillRemaining(TabBarView)
     ])
```

So the TabBarView contains a Column on one tab, that overflows the screen. The issue is, that even though SliverFillRemaining is obviously not the right choice for the overflowing Widget but sadly as TabBarView looses the hasSize property of its children, I don't know what other Widget I could use to get the layout going. The goal is to achieve something like this (shows the current overflow):

[image: Wireframe]

EDIT: Here is a working example on DartPad: https://dartpad.dev/bda4cc5fd2aea292310fe05daa440760

Comment: I can see that your code is workable, but `tabview` is something which I am concerned about. Please post the `Tab` and it's `TabBarView` in your question. I will be able to help you more on that then :)

Comment: @Alok Yes the code works, again my problem is the overflow. The Tab has to overflow by design, but I get an Overflow Error and don't know how to make this Work without it.

Comment: Please post your full Tab and TabBarView code in your question. We will be able to help you more on that :)

Comment: @Alok added an DartPad link that shows my problem.

Comment: @T.Tos how did you resolve this?

Comment: @Brendan I switched to NestedScrollView, but used the package extended_nested_scroll_view to make this layout work. This kind of messes up scrolling behaviour and since it's been a year there might be a better solution already.

Answer (score 0):

try using [extended_nested_scroll_view](https://pub.dev/packages/extended_nested_scroll_view), maybe that's what you looking for

Answer (score -3):

add    floating: true, under pinned: true,

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.